# How to create a "Pressing Effect" for a button in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have created an ImageButton in my game. It has a listener and I have also added a texture, it works just fine but I couldn't find how to add a pressing effect to my buttons. Is there any premade libGDX method, or an easy way to have a pressing effect for my buttons?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ImageButtonStyle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle.html) to create a styling for your button, that automatically changes it's texture. [This LibGDX Tutorial](https://libgdx.info/buttons-scene2d/) explains the use of buttons and button styles.

Basically you need to do something like this (from the tutorial):

```
ImageButton button3 = new ImageButton(mySkin);
button3.getStyle().imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("switch_off.png"))));
button3.getStyle().imageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("switch_on.png"))));
```

If the button is handled by a `Stage`, like the following, it should be handled automatically:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
  private Stage stage;
  @Override
  public void create () {
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    // TODO create the button

    // add the button to the stage
    stage.addActor(button3);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
  }
}
```